# arrow function with brackets giving wrong answer

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

```
const shouldCancelExam = grades => {
    return grades.some(grade=>{grade>=18});
}
```

the above gives False for `shouldCancelExam([10, 12, 10, 18])`

However, the below is giving the correct output which is True. What is causing the difference?

```
const shouldCancelExam = grades => {
    return grades.some(grade=> grade>=18);
}
```

Comment: The second example uses implicit return. The first returns nothing from the callback function.

Comment: To explain a bit further, by wrapping in brackets it changes from a return value to a block of code to be run

Comment: `return grades.some(grade=>{ return grade>=18 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember that when you use arrow function and have a single statement  you do not require {} if you using {} then you have to write return type keyword

```
    const shouldCancelExam = grades => {
            return grades.some(grade=> {
                             return grade>=18
    });
 }


const shouldCancelExam = grades => {
            return grades.some(grade=> grade>=18);
        }
```